# How to specify more than one stylesheet

Tags: php, html, css

So i've been working through some exercises in a PHP book i bought, and they suggested styling a header and saving it as a separate document, then when you want to use it in your pages, you just use

```
<?php
   require('header.html');
?>
```

Whilst this saves a crap load of code for modifying the header of each individual page, i wish to use different stylesheets for different pages.. but i dont know how to, since when the header.html is called, it automatically loads its own stylesheet..

Is there like an "IF" statement i can use to determine which one i can use? do stylesheet specificatuions have to be in the `<head>`?

Comment: Maybe you should keep on reading that book of yours. Looks like you haven't come very far yet.

Comment: Now, i went way past that point, and it didnt say anything.. it doesnt go into html at all really, just suggested using that

Comment: @amartin94 Keep reading.

Comment: Consider having your header as PHP file rather than plain HTML. Then you can do whatever PHP magic you can imagine in there.

Comment: Here's a starting point: if you want dynamic or conditional content in the header, as you do here, you should be including a `header.php` file not a `header.html` file, then use variables in `header.php` to determine what to output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, here's an example.

In `index.php` (*the file which will be accessed*)

```
<?php
    $stylesheets = [
        '/stylesheets/common.css',
        '/stylesheets/themes.css',
    ];
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include("head.php"); ?>
    </head>
</html>
```

And in `head.php`:

```
<?php foreach ($stylesheets as $stylesheet): ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= $stylesheet ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The output should be something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/common.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/themes.css" />
    </head>
</html>
```

**Why?**

Because you assign to `$stylesheets` an array of values (*URIs to stylesheets*). When you include the file `head.php`, the variable `$stylesheets` is available to it because it was declared/assigned before inclusion.

`head.php` then simply iterates over the values and spews them out. By changing the value of `$stylesheets` you can add or remove stylesheet references from the resulting page.

This is fraught with issues though; absence of error-checking, etc., and will need a lot more work before you can reliably use something like this in production (*or should need a lot more work anyway*)

Comment: @amartin94 - Maybe grab the markup as a string or capture the `include` with `ob_get_clean()` and use `{{template_variable}}` to $header =`str_replace('{{the_styles}}', $the_goods, $the_header);` Or a template in conjunction with `body` class-based theming and only one CSS include. Or have the file be `site.css.php` with a `header('Content-type: text/css');` and put `@import url($url)` within like what's done above. There's a lot of ways to decorator pattern. In the long run a routing pattern should be overlaid to enforce sanity. Take a look at Slim Framework, it's pretty concise. Or Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

Don't include that portion of your header.  This way you can also properly title and keyword each page  ie

```
<html>
<head>
<title Yada yada</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link href="style/customstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<?php require_once('header.html'); ?>
```

YOUR SITE HERE

Then in your header.html finish your tags off

```
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
....
</head>
<body>
<div class....>
 Your Header (topbar /menu etc..
```

Comment: Please include a proper Doctype too avoid quirks mode hell. BTW, your `title` tag isn't closed properly.